# Getting erroneous index while iterating stream Java 8

Tags: java-8

The part of our application reads csv file and converts it into a list of equivalent java objects. Further processing is done as follows

```
List<MyDO> dataList = ...
try{    
       List<MyDO> processedList = dataList
               .stream()
               .filter(...)//some filter condition
               .map(...)//some validation & processing
               .collect(Collectors.toList());  
}catch(Exception e){
  logger.error("Invalid data found at "+i);
}
```

It is required to get index(i) at which the invalid data such as non parsable int value was found. I tried using IntStream like

```
IntStream.range(0, dataList.size())
        .filter(i -> ...)
        .mapToObj(i -> {
             MyDO myDO = dataList.get(i);
             ...// some error at i
         })
        .collect(toList());
```

But, that erroneous `i` can't be assigned to a variable outside the stream. Can this index be taken out and logged?

Comment: Try this one `IntStream.rangeClosed(0,dataList.size())
                .mapToObj(i->{
                    if (i>8)
                        throw new IllegalArgumentException(String.valueOf(i));
                    return i;
                }).collect(Collectors.toList());
        }catch (Exception e){
           list.add(Integer.valueOf(e.getMessage()));
        }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just provide the context information in a dedicated exception.

```
IntStream.range(0, dataList.size())
    .filter(i -> ...)
    .mapToObj(i -> {
         MyDO myDO = dataList.get(i);
         try {
         ...// some error at i
         } catch(Exception ex) {
             throw new IllegalStateException("at index "+i, ex);
         }
     })
    .collect(toList());
```

You could also use a custom exception type holding the index as an `int` value for easier processing (in case you want to do more than just logging). That exception could also take the relevant `MyDO`.

Generally, it might be simpler to use an ordinary loop here:

```
List<MyDO> processedList = new ArrayList<>(dataList.size());
for(int i = 0, num = dataList.size(); i < num; i++) {
    if(...) { // your filter criteria
        MyDO myDO = dataList.get(i);
        try {
        ...// some error at i
        } catch(Exception ex) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("at index "+i, ex);
        }
        processedList.add(myDO);
    }
}
```

or

```
List<MyDO> processedList = new ArrayList<>(dataList.size());
for(int i = 0, num = dataList.size(); i < num; i++) {
    if(...) { // your filter criteria
        MyDO myDO = dataList.get(i);
        try {
        ...// some error at i
        } catch(Exception ex) {
            logger.error("Invalid data found at "+i);
            break;
        }
        processedList.add(myDO);
    }
}
```

to get the effect of your example exception handler.